# R getting error of number of rows when using replace function

Tags: r, function, replace, dataframe

I'm trying to get rid of some specific words in a data frame column. So the data set looks like somewhat like this with 3235 rows:

```
V1                            V2
AUTAUGA COUNTY                1
BALDWIN COUNTY                3
VALDEZ-CORDOVA CENSUS AREA    261
```

what I'm trying to do is:

```
data$V1 <- replace(data$V1, " COUNTY", "")
```

But I get an error that looks like this:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "V1", value = c("AUTAUGA COUNTY",  : 
   replacement has 3236 rows, data has 3235
```

Am I using the function the wrong way? Or is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove the `COUNTY` with `''`, you can use `sub` i.e. `sub(' COUNTY', '', data$V1)`

Comment: `replace` replaces whole elements of vectors by index, not by matching substrings like sub, gsub, chartr, etc. at least I think, the documentation of `?replace` is horrendous

Comment: @rawr Also, I think the 'list' part in `?replace` seems to be logical or numeric index.  But, the OP uses just ' COUNTY' which may not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hugo,
For the example you've provided, this code works well:

```
eg <- data.frame(V1 = c("AUTUAGA COUNTY", "BALDWIN COUNTY",
                        "VALDEZ-CORDOVA CENSUS AREA"),
                 V2 = c(1, 3, 261))
eg$gsub <- gsub(" COUNTY", "", eg$V1)
eg
-                           V1  V2                       gsub
- 1             AUTUAGA COUNTY   1                    AUTUAGA
- 2             BALDWIN COUNTY   3                    BALDWIN
- 3 VALDEZ-CORDOVA CENSUS AREA 261 VALDEZ-CORDOVA CENSUS AREA
```

Does this resolve the error?

(Edited to fix the output column names.)

Comment: Based on your code, the output will have only 2 columns.

Comment: @ElizabethAB this solve the problem exactly what I needed, the number of columns was not necesarily needed to be the same at the end, but I can play with this for options.

Comment: @HugoHK - if you change the command to, `eg$V1 <- gsub(" COUNTY", "", eg$V1)` it will overwrite the V1 column and NOT create a new one. I only wrote it as creating a new column so you could see the before and after.

Comment: @ElizabethAB Thanks! I got it! I actually needed both ways, so I made the code fit with your suggestion.